# Why existing Maven repository is missing?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I have following pom.xml configuration

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.library</groupId>
    <artifactId>library-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.5.Final</hibernate.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.5.Release</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- SPRING -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- END OF SPRING -->

        <!-- LOG4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- END OF LOG4j -->

        <!-- DATABASE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.33</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- END OF DATABASE -->
        <!-- SECURITY -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.passay</groupId>
            <artifactId>passay</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- REST -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JUNIT -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I receive the information - "Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.5.FINAL". Why is that? On mavenrepository site I can clearly see the repo. Is modelversion responsible for this?

Comment: mavenrepository site is not Maven Central which is https://repo1.maven.org/ Searching in Maven Central can be done via https://search.maven.org

Answer (score 3):

Please 
try
**5.2.5.Final** instead **5.2.5.FINAL**
Case sensitive.

Comment: The problem still exists

Comment: @HansSchwimmer:  Is it still referring to the all-caps JAR or is it referring to the lowercase JAR?

Comment: @Makoto lowercase JAR

Comment: @Makoto now it is: Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.5.Final

Comment: Please paste here your last pom.xml if possible.

Comment: @zsair please check out my main post - I edited it with whole pom.xml

Comment: 4.3.5.Release must be 4.3.5.RELEASE  . Again case sensitivity. Please use http://search.maven.org and copy/paste dependencies from there. You will suffer less. In spring.version you will have 4.3.5.RELEASE and in hibernate.version 5.2.5.Final.

Comment: <properties>
            <hibernate.version>5.2.5.Final</hibernate.version>
            <spring.version>4.3.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132562/discussion-between-zsair-and-hans-schwimmer).

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

So your pom should look like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>hibernate.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>final</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: @HansSchwimmer This one is working for me. What error are you getting?

Comment: If I lower down to 4.3.5 it works                                                                        Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.5.Final

Comment: @HansSchwimmer Try the one that i just posted.

Comment: I updated my post with whole pom.xml. Please check it out

Comment: If I lower down hibernate version to 4.3.5 it works. Why it doesn't work for 5.2.5?

Comment: @HansSchwimmer can you try it without using the properties. I mean by commenting out the properties tag.

Comment: I did that and problem is still there